NextJs react-hook-form not showing passed in values
I am using NextJs (app router) for my front end. I load the data at the server layer and pass the value to the 'client only' UI component.
React-hook-form is not showing the values supplied as an arguemnt. As values are passed to the page useEffect is not required.
When I log the value passed, it shows the expected values.
Can you help identify why the form is not displaying the values?
UI page header:
 export default function PersonalDetailsUI({
 userAccount,
 }: {
    userAccount: USER_TYPE;
 }) {..... }

default value
const defaultValues: USER_CONTACT_TYPE = {
    id: userAccount.id,
    title: userAccount.title,
    displayName: userAccount.displayName,
    firstName: userAccount.firstName,
    lastName: userAccount.lastName,
    email: userAccount.email,
    mobPhone: userAccount.mobPhone,
    street: address.street,
    street2: address.street2,
    town: address.town,
    county: address.county,
    postCode: address.postCode,
    birthDate: userAccount.birthDate,
}

useForm with default values passed in
const {
    control,    
    formState: { errors },
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
} = useForm<USER_CONTACT_TYPE>({defaultValues});

Use of the Controller to display the value:
<Controller
                            name="title"
                            control={control}
                            
                            render={({ field, fieldState }) => (
                                <>
                                    <label
                                        htmlFor={field.name}
                                        className={classNames({
                                            'p-error': errors.title,
                                        })}></label>
                                    <span className="p-float-label">
                                        <InputText
                                            id={field.name}
                                            autoFocus={true}
                                            width={'100%'}
                                            className={classNames({
                                                'p-invalid': fieldState.error,
                                            })}
                                            onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e.target.value)}
                                        />
                                        <label htmlFor={field.name}>Title</label>
                                    </span>
                                    {getFormErrorMessage(field.name)}
                                </>
                            )}
                        />

Thank you
